# Get Logical File name from BLOB DB backup

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I want to get logical file names of the DB from the backup which is placed in the BLOB.

I was able to implement the same when the backup is placed at local server. However the same script is not working for the BLOB path.

```
$restoreObject = new-object('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Restore')
$bdi = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.BackupDeviceItem') ($BackupPath, 'File')
$restoreObject.Devices.Add($bdi)
$fl = $restoreObject.ReadFileList($DestinationSQLServer)
$PhysicalNameSet=$fl.PhysicalName
$logicalNameSet=$fl.logicalName
```

The above script works absolutely fine when the `$BackupPath` is a local server path. But throws the below error when I give a BLOB path.

> Exception calling "ReadFileList" with "1" argument(s): "An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch."

What am I missing to get the logical names of the DB from the BLOB backup?

Comment: Try specifying `Url` for the [`DeviceType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.devicetype?view=sql-smo-140.17283.0) instead of `File`;

Comment: Have tried that option as well, still the same error throws up